# How to generate a Unique Identifier on Data which is of fixed size ?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Suppose if my data size is always 100 characters/bytes, Is there any way to generate a Unique Identifier (whose lenght is less than 100) and without any collisions.

Comment: Does the calculation have to be repeatable? I.e. if you have 100 bytes, and I have the same 100 bytes, do you want both of us to be able to calculate the same identifier independently?

Comment: How unique are we talking here?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution with which I should be able re-generate the same Unique Identifier as my data never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There are 2^800 = 6.668*10^240 different possible 100-byte strings.

There are only 2^0 + 2^8 + 2^16 + ... + 2^792 = 2.615*10^238 different possible strings of length 99 bytes or less.

It's not possible to match each of 6.668*10^240 men up with a woman of his own if there are only 2.615*10^238 women to go around.

Comment: Appreciate for providing the answer with an explanation but frankly speaking being a layman, I am lost trying to figure out the explanation that you have provided. :)

Would it be possible for you to explain it in much more simple terms ?

Comment: In order to *guarantee* collision avoidance, you need to somehow write a function that transforms *every possible* 100-byte string into a unique string.  (Suppose to the contrary that there were 2 100-byte input strings that your function gave the same output string for: Then if those 2 strings happen to be used as inputs to the function, you get a collision.)  ...

Comment: ...  There are 6.668*10^240 possible different 100-byte strings, each of which *could* be an input to this function you want to write -- that means that it needs to be able to produce at least the same number of different *output* strings.  (Clear so far?)  But you have given the constraint that the output string must be 99 characters or less, and if we count up the number of different possible such strings (2^0 = 1 of length 0, 2^8 = 256 of length 1, 2^16 = 65536 of length 2, etc., based on 8 bits per byte) then we wind up with only 2.615*10^238 different possible output strings. ...

Comment: ...  Since the number of possible output strings is *less than* the number of possible input strings, there's no way to assign a distinct output string to each input string -- meaning that it's impossible to write the function you want to write.  (The "men" are the inputs to the function, and the "women" are the outputs.)  Clearer now?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for compression rather than hashing. Hashing has collisions by definition, they are just very unlikely in good hash algorithms.